# Clear recent app list in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I am making an application which creates a lock screen. The problem is that there is a way from recent app button, from where i can enter into device without entering the password into my lock screen.I have closed the recent app dialog by ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS. But it's not too fast to close it and i can click any recent app on this dialog. What can be the solution for it? I am trying to clear the recent app list, how can i do that? or is there any better way to handle this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have u tried using onResume()

Comment: No, What should i do on onResume? I have tried on onPause and onStop, I call my lock screen again in onPause and onStop.